# Dissolve does not fully dissolve lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

I dissolved a polyline feature (streets) on the following fields:
WHOLESTNAM, NUMBEROFLANES, THOROUGHFA, SPEEDLIMIT, GEOID

and asked the dissolve to take an average of the AADT field.

Why does the result contain features that are exactly the same on the 5 fields I dissolved on?

Shouldn't these have dissolved into a single feature?

[image: Fields exactly the same after dissolve]

Comment: What parameters did you use for the dissolve? It looks like you've specified 'no multi-part' and you have lines that aren't perfectly snapped at the ends.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Looks like I did not select "Create multipart features" or "unsplit lines."

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happened.  GEOID is Census Block Groups.  Many streets run along Census Block Group boundaries.  So streets were split whenever they entered one Census Block Group or the other, creating many separate parts even when the other fields - such as Street Name - were equivalent.